# Compare two values in a single column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have a SQL Server database in which I ran a query that collects the data about two different tournamnets and the number of people enrolled in the tournament.  So for instance the output is:

```
Name of Tourney    People enrolled
Tourney 1 ----------- 7
Tourney 2 ----------- 8
```

After getting these two values, I want to be able to compare them and only show the information for the tournmanet that contains the highest number of people enrolled. Should all be in one query...how can I do this?

Comment: Are all of the results delimited the same way?

Comment: Yes they are. I am new to Database but I was doing a COUNT on People AS 'People Enrolled' which gives me the values of 7 and 8.  I want to then say since 8 is the largest value, here is the name of the tournamnet (maybe some details as well)

Comment: @jscott beacuse the tourney with the least number of people cannot be in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MS SQL Server, this should do the trick:

```
select top 1 ...
from ...
where ...
order by "people enrolled" desc
```

This sorts your results DESC so that the row with the largest number of people enrolled is first. Then returns the TOP 1 record - that is, the first row, thus the row with the largest number of people enrolled.

Comment: I only can have a single result, the largest number of people enrolled

Comment: that's what TOP 1 , with the ORDER BY will do - sort the result to have the largest number of people enrolled as first record and return only the TOP 1 row (i.e. the first row).

Comment: Ahh...I see that now, sorry i am new to database.  That works thank you!!